# Horizontal geom_bar with no overlaps, equal bar widths, and customized axis tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Probably a simple `ggplot2` question.

I have a `data.frame` with a `numeric` value, a categorical (`factor`) value, and a `character` value:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(log10.p.value=c(-2.5,-2.5,-2.5,-2.39,-2,-1.85,-1.6,-1.3,-1.3,-1),
                 direction=sample(c("up","down"),10,replace = T),
                 label=paste0("label",1:10),stringsAsFactors = F) %>% dplyr::arrange(log10.p.value)
df$direction <- factor(df$direction,levels=c("up","down"))
```

I want to plot these data as a `barplot` using `geom_bar`, where the bars are horizontal and their lengths are determined by `df$log10.p.value`, their color by `df$direction`, and the `y-axis` `tick` labels are `df$label`, where the bars are vertically ordered by `df$log10.p.value`.

As you can see `df$log10.p.value` are not unique, hence:

```
ggplot(df,aes(log10.p.value))+geom_bar(aes(fill=direction))+theme_minimal()+coord_flip()+ylab("log10(p-value)")+xlab("")
```

Gives me:
[image]

How do I:

1. Make the bars not overlap each other.
2. Have the same width.
3. Be separated by a small margin?
4. Have the `y-axis` `tick` labels be `df$label`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Please note that, by default, `geom_bar` determines the bar length using frequency/count. So, you need to specify `stat = "identity"` for value mapping.

```
# since all of your values are negative the graph is on the left side
ggplot(df, aes(x = label, y = log10.p.value, fill = direction)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() + 
  ylab("log10(p-value)") +
  xlab("")
```